# Create .done File in SFTP server using Python

Tags: python, sftp

I want to upload a file to SFTP server using Python script and create {filename}.done when the file transfer completes to make sure transfer was successful. Can anybody help me on this how I can achieve this task?

And, by the way, I already have working code to transfer the main file using paramiko python module. I just need suggestion on how to automatically create .done file.

Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? Do you have working code to transfer the first file? Or are you asking generally how to transfer files? Please [edit] your question to include any relevant source code that you have.

Comment: Thank you  http://stackoverflow.com/users/13317/ for the suggestion. I just updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the file you want to create and close it.

```
f = sftp.open(FOLDER + '/test', 'w')
f.close()
```

By the way, there are some examples of this on Paramiko [test cases](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/tests/test_sftp.py)

Comment: Thank you so much http://stackoverflow.com/users/172306/fn . 
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @IshworBhatta On Stack Overflow, we thank by accepting the answer!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for reminding me. I just forgot to do so. :)